# Multiple pages with standalone

Tags: standalone

I have a number of figures and I want to create a document with LaTeX such that each page is one of the figures (with the page size equal to the size of the figure).

If I use

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{fig1.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

I get a nice single page which is the size of my original .pdf file.  But I'd like to plot 2 files in two separate pages, each page the size of its .pdf file.

I've tried

```
\documentclass[multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%
\includegraphics{fig1.pdf}%
\newpage
%
\includegraphics{fig2.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

But this produces 2 pages, but the pages are larger than the original figures (here's one page): [image]

Is there a way to get what I'm after?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What I use is

```
\documentclass[multi=my,crop]{standalone}
```

After this, wrap every figure into `\begin{my}…\end{my}`.

Comment: Works for me (`crop` doesn't change anything). With `multi=page` and `\begin{page}...` this gets more intuitive.

Comment: You can also use \standaloneenv{tikzpicture} to tell standalone to start a new page for every tikzpicture. This line must come after \usepackage{tikz}.

Answer (score 4):

I understand you already have some `pdf` figures, each one in an independent file and you want to obtain a booklet where each page shows one figure and each page is adjusted to figure size.

If my supposition is correct, you need [`incgraph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/incgraph) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{incgraph}

\begin{document}

\incgraph{1943}

\incgraph{1842}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put `fig1.pdf` and `fig2.pdf` into a single PDF with each page exactly equal to the original pdf, then I recommend you use the `pdftk` program.

```
pdftk fig1.pdf fig2.pdf cat output newfile.pdf
```

Comment: I'm after a LaTeX solution.  I'm ultimately going to be using `psfrag` (so .eps files) to  change some labels in many figures.